# Catch connection timeout and page not found exception?

Tags: java, exception

I am using a third party api to get user authentication in spring.
I need to catch the exceptions that occur when trying to connect to that api, like connection time out and page not found (if their server is down).
Right now I am trying to do this with below code. Is this sufficient to catch these exceptions?

```
public boolean userAuthentication(String userName) {
    try {
         if(hasAccess(userName)) {
            return true;
         } else {
            return false;
         }
    } catch (IOException e) {
         logger.info("exception occured "+ e);
         return false;
    }
}
```

Here hasAccess is the third party api, I cannot change that method. Whereas I need to catch these exception and give appropriate response to the user.

Comment: Can't say more without looking at the `hasAccess()` method signature. Ideally, it should throw exceptions accordingly and you should have catch clauses to match.

Comment: For all other exceptions, I can catch them accordingly. But the problem is I need to catch the exception if the url I am trying to hit is down or some thing like connection time out took place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does hasAccess(String) define any throws statement?

Does it define that it throws IOException?

Do you have the access to the source code of this method? If you do then you can go and and check if they are handling any exceptions thrown or they are re-throwing any runtime exceptions.

To be on safer side, you should catch runtime exceptions, as the error is unpredictable for you, so you can gracefully handle errors.

Comment: As you said, i went through source code. I turns out they are throwing a custom runtime exception. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to tell whether this is sufficient without looking at the implementation of `hasAccess()`, since that is the function that will throw the error.

However, if you really need to catch this exception, you can always use

```
try {
    if (hasAccess(userName)){}
} catch (Exception e) {
    //caught
}
```

This isn't always good practice, since Exception will catch every exception, but it is a solution if you're looking for one.